# I'm getting identifier expected error

Tags: visual-c++

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstnum = Convert.ToInt32(lbldisplay.Text);
        lbldisplay.="0";
        operation = "/";
    }
}
```

i am witting a calculator and I get an error in visual studio 2013 at this line`lbldisplay.="0";`
it says identifier expected, cant find where the problem is

Comment: you have extra dot "." in line  lbldisplay.="0";  removed that

Comment: than i get this error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Comment: you cannot direct use string value to Label. use this   lbldisplay.Text ="0";

Comment: if i use that bro than the button doesn't divide the numbers it just replaces them with 0

Comment: actually, I am not understand what is your objective, I just give Answer for what you get "identifier expected"...now to solve your current issue you have to tell us What Exactly you ant to do...and what is not working

Comment: i am trying to write a calculator and wen i write the code for the dicision option it doesent work

Answer (score 1):

you have extra dot "." in line `lbldisplay.="0";` Use Property `lbldisplay` of  What you want to use

```
lbldisplay.Text ="0";
```